# Plot a curve while there is an open figure

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

When I run my program, the result are shown in a figure.

Now, when I want to plot each of my parameters available in the workspace, I have to close the previous figure, so that the new one can be opened!

Is there any way that I could plot new figures without closing the existed one?

Comment: Do you want to plot multiple things on the same axes or do you just want a new figure window for each one? Or perhaps a [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select multiple variables, and right click -> plot as multiple series.

But if you want separate figures, just issue a `figure` command prior to plotting:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);

figure
plot(x,sin(x),'b',  x,cos(x),'r')
title('sine & cosine')

figure
plot(x,tan(x),'b')
title('tangent')
```

Comment: I wanted to have another window which I  could do it with your hint.
Thanks a lot Rody

Answer (score 1):

You can open up new figures using the [figure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html) command, like so:

```
t = 1:100;
y = sin(t);

figure
plot(t,y)
```

You can also change the title bar of individual figures by including a number in parentheses after the command:

```
t = 1:100;
y1 = sin(t);
y2 = sin(0.5.*t);

figure(1) % Title bar here will show "Figure 1"
plot(t,y1)

figure(2) % Title bar here will show "Figure 2"
plot(t,y2)
```